# How to gray out a panel in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I created a `matlab` GUI for a robot arm testing.

Before program executes the program waits some configurations, like first panel for conf file input browse and result file browse setting, second panel for entering robots ip adres an so on.

I have 5 panel like this and i want to gray out panels and open them one by one after clicking next button.

I have tried:

```
set(hObject,'Enable','off');
drawnow;
```

But these solutions does not work because ENABLE parameter is not suitable for panels (The name 'Enable' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'uipanel'.).

I could not find any solution for panels. Do you have any suggestion? (Next panel will be shade off after clicking NEXT pushbutton at previous panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `uipanel` children `Enable` property:

```
set(get(hObject,'Children'),'Enable','off')
```

This will set all child objects enable property.

A more complete way would be to extend this to check which Children are uicontrols:

```
% extract all children
children = get(hObject,'Children');
% only set children which are uicontrols:
set(children(strcmpi ( get (children,'Type'),'UIControl')),'enable','off')
```

Comment: It works for initial opening. How to configure the the code in that way for example if im at 2. panel the 1. and 3. panel wil be shade out and each panel has next and previous button. How do i send a grayout commend under a button to a panel?

Comment: You need to link to the appropriate handles of each of the panels (And respective children).  They will probably be stored in your handles structure